# numpy matrix as argument to method

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to pass a numpy matrix to an object method but I keep getting TypeError: test_obj() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

I think the matrix object is not getting interpreted properly as a matrix object, however when the same code is run as simple function it works fine.  How can I get my object method to work like the simple function?

code:

```
from numpy import *

class Tester(object):
    def test_obj(x):
        print 'test obj:', type(x)

    def test_fun(x):
        print 'test fun:', type(x)

X = matrix('5.0 7.0')

test_fun(X)

tester = Tester()
tester.test_obj(X)
```

output:

```
test fun: <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fornarim/test_matrix.py", line 22, in <module>
    tester.test_obj(X)
TypeError: test_obj() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All objects' methods take an implicit **self** argument, so your method test_fun must be

```
def test_fun(self,arg):
```

Unlike in Java, in Python you must refer back to the object.

As mentioned below, also possible is using the @staticmethod decorator to indicate that the function does not need a reference to the object.

```
@staticmethod
def test_fun(arg):
```

Comment: Or, in case your `test_obj` method does not in anyway depend on or alter the state of the object (but is somehow logically linked to it and therefore you prefer defining it as part of the class instead of as a simple function), you can also use the `@staticmethod` decorator to annotate the function -- it then does not need a `self` argument.

Comment: Thanks, and I added to the answer, but I have a feeling the op wants it in as part of his Tester object

Comment: Yes, I think your original answer is what he needed, but it's nicer to be complete :) I noted that your answer and your edit (I think) to his question got things a bit wrong now, though: In his original question `test_fun` referred to a function (not a method) and `test_obj` was a method of the `Tester` object. Now in the question `test_fun` and `test_obj` are identical except for the name.